# Create the list X to Y without numbers have same digits (11, 22, 33 etc)

Tags: python

I need to print all the numbers in the list that do not have same digits ex: 22,33.

```
x,y=list(map(int,input().split()))
l=[]
m=[]
for i in range(x,y+1):
    l.append(i)
    for j in range(0,len(l)):
        unit = l[j] % 10 
        while (l[j] != 0):
            curr = l[j] %10
            l[j]=l[j]//10
            if(curr != unit):
                m.append(l[j])
        print(m)
```

Sample input: `10,20`

Sample output: `10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20` (11 is removed)

my output: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: what errors, also provide sample input and output

Comment: Your code produces no error when the input is provided as `22 33`. How are you entering your input and what error are you getting? (add it to the question, not as a comment)

Comment: Updated with sample output and mine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. "I have some code to solve an overall task; I get this wrong output" still does not make a proper question.

Comment: Positive integer `n` has no repeated digits if `len(str(n)) == len(set(str(n)))` therefore `result = [n for n in range(x, y + 1) if len(str(n)) == len(set(str(n)))]`

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample of input and output, you want to remove the numbers which have the same digits.

So here is the solution:

```
x, y = list(map(int,input().split()))
ans = []

for i in range(x, y + 1):
    list_num = list(str(i))
    if list_num.count(str(i % 10)) != len(str(i)):
        ans.append(i)

print(*ans)
```

Comment: I would suggest not calling `str(i)` more than once. More specifically, that could be a requirement to **not use** strings at all. Otherwise, `% 10` + `// 10` seem out of place in the question

Comment: @OneCricketeer So if the author explains it in details, than I can edit it ^^

Answer (score 0):

`range()` returns an iterator. You dont care about previous or future numbers, so you dont need to store any lists other than your outputs

Focus on isolating your logic. What does it mean for a number to have all the same digit? For instance, if you uniquely count all digits to be 1, then you have the same digit. Make it a function

```
from collections import defaultdict
def all_same(x):
    vals = defaultdict(int)
    while x != 0:
        x, tens = divmod(x, 10)
        vals[tens] += 1
    return len(vals) == 1

x, y = list(map(int,input().split()))
print(','.join( str(v) for v in range(x, y + 1) if not all_same(v) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x, y = list(map(int, input().split()))

result = []

for i in range(x, y+1):
    counts = [0] * 10
    n = i
    while n > 0:
        n, remainder = divmod(n, 10)
        counts[remainder] += 1
    if max(counts) == 1:
        result.append(i)
```

If you are allowed to convert your number to string you can do

```
result = [n for n in range(x, y + 1) if len(str(n)) == len(set(str(n)))]
```